# How to move multiple grouped Sprite images simultaneously in Pygame Sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am making a game with groups of birds, when I press a key I want all the birds to move at the same time but only one is moving.

There are five birds that I create with a loop, but only one of them is moving.

How can I move all of them at the same time

```py
class Birds(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, width, height, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.image = pygame.image.load(
            os.path.join("Assets", image)).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (80, 70))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [self.pos_x, self.pos_y]
      

    def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if(keys[pygame.K_u]):

            if self.pos_x > 400 or self.pos_x < 0:
                pos_x, pos_y = self.rect.center
                pos_x -= 5
                self.rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)

birds_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

for target in range(5):
    new_target = Birds("birds.png", 100, 100,
                       random.randrange(0, BACKGROUND_WIDTH), 
                       random.randrange(0, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT // 3), 3, 3)
    birds_sprite.add(new_target)
   

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
       
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(BACKGROUND_IMAGE, (1000, 540))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # gunhunter.shoot()
    WIN.blit(picture, (0, 0))

    birds_sprite.draw(WIN)
    
    new_target.movement()

    birds_sprite.update()
  
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the method `movement` in a loop for each object in the group `birds_sprite`:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    for target in birds_sprite:
        target.movement()

    # [...]
```

---

Alter natively you can implement an `update` method. Just rename `movement` to `update`. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group.

```py
class Birds(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        # [...]
```

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    birds_sprite.update()

    # [...]
``´
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, but i have managed to make it work.

```
enemyList = []
for target in range(5):
  new_target = Birds("birds.png", 100, 100,
                   random.randrange(0, BACKGROUND_WIDTH),         random.randrange(0, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT // 3), 2, 4)
  enemyList.append(new_target)
  birds_sprite.add(new_target)
```

then a function

```
def movement(self, thegroup):
    for i in thegroup:
        pos_x, pos_y = i.rect.center
        pos_x += i.speed_x
        pos_y += i.speed_y
        i.rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)
        if(pos_x >= 900 or pos_x < 0):
            i.speed_x = - i.speed_x
            print(pos_x)
        if(pos_y >= 300 or pos_y < 0):
            i.speed_y = - i.speed_y
            print(pos_y)
```

Then inside while loop

```
new_target.movement(enemyList)
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing I did in my answer. The answer is that you need a loop. When you use a `pygame.spriteGroup` you should use `update` and implement an `update` method in the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class.